# Firebase auth, problems with google sign up overriding other emails

Tags: firebase-authentication

When signing up a user with email and password, or any other sign in method, with an email example@gmail.com. And then when signing in with google , with example@gmail.com, the google sign in overrides that previous email that was already used.
Here are the functions I'm using:
For email and password:

```
 const handleSignup = () => {
 console.log('signup')
clearErrors()
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(err => {
    
    switch(err.code) {
    case "auth/email-already-in-use":
      setEmailError(err.message)
      break
    case "auth/invalid-email":
      setEmailError(err.message)
    break
    case "auth/weak-password":
      setPasswordError(err.message)
    break
    default: 
    setEmailError('Invalid')
  }
})
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
      user.updateProfile({
        displayName: name,
      }) 
      db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
          created: new Date(), 
          msgids,
          uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
          online: true, 
          userinfo: {
            name,
            cover,
            age: '', 
            phone: '', 
            city: '',
            country: '',
            website: 'https://',
            job: '',
            email,
          },
          customization: {
            color: '#10325c',
            themecolor: '#0f6ce6',
            darkmode: false,
            widemode: false,
          }
      })
      db.collection('notifications').doc(user.uid).set({
        notifications: []
      })

  }//if (user)
  else {
    setUser('')
  } 
}) 
}
```

For Google:

```
 function loginwithGoogle(){
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('email');

firebase.auth()
.signInWithPopup(provider)
.then((result) => {
  if(result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser){
        /** @type {firebase.auth.OAuthCredential} */
  var credential = result.credential;

  // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
  var token = credential.accessToken;
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  // ...
  db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
    created: new Date(), 
    msgids,
    uid: user.uid,
    online: true, 
    userinfo: {
      name: user.displayName,
      cover: user.photoURL,
      age: '', 
      phone: user.phoneNumber, 
      city:'',
      country: '',
      website: 'https://',
      job: '',
      email:user.email
    },
    customization: {
      color: '#10325c',
      themecolor: '#0f6ce6',
      darkmode: false,
      widemode: false,
    }
})
db.collection('notifications').doc(user.uid).set({
  notifications: []
})
  }

}).catch((error) => {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
  setEmailError(error.message)
  setTimeout(()=>{
    setEmailError('')
  },3000)
});
}
```

Any idea why google sign up is overriding other email?

Comment: Have you had any luck figuring this out Josh? I'm having the same issue, and when a user (who registered with an email and password) tries to login, it says that the password does not match, but without any other reasons why.

Comment: Actually, i realized that it doesnt matter, because the userid will remain the  same if they login with the same email with different providers

Comment: Right but if they create an account with an email and password, and then login with google using the same email and password they wont be able to log in using the email and password they previously created.